# PHP Use array map to reOrder an array

Tags: php, arrays, array-map

I need to reOrder this array with one function.

From (My actual array):

```
array:2 [▼
  0 => array:2 [▼
    "way" => 0
    "period" => "MONTH"
  ]
  1 => array:2 [▼
    "way" => 1
    "period" => "3MONTHS"
  ]
]
```

To (I would like this array):

```
array:2 [▼
  0 => array:1 [▼
    "MONTH" => 0
  ]
  1 => array:1 [▼
    "3MONTHS" => 1
  ]
]
```

Can I do that with `array_map()` function?

Comment: Why don't you try and see if you can?

Comment: You probably look for `array_column()`.

Comment: expected is wrong . inner array have one element and you showed  `array:2`

Comment: @Anant  it's handmade array :)

Comment: @splash58 . yes you are right, but it will more good if people added real array so that it is easy to copy and execute directly with programs

Comment: @Anant just a copy paste mistake. I'm gonna edit that

Comment: @KevinR  hey no issue. you have answer below. check and mark+up-vote if worked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply use `foreach` instead like as

```
foreach($your_arr as &$v){
    $v = [$v["period"] => $v["way"]];
}
print_r($your_arr);
```

Or using `array_map`

```
$your_arr = array_map(function($v){ return [$v["period"] => $v["way"]]; },$your_arr);
print_r($your_arr);
```

Answer (score 2):

Use **[array_column()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php)** as

```
$data = array_column($array, 'way','period');
```

That convert `period` as key and `way` as its value