# Change the content of an array to be more efficient

Tags: php, arrays

When doing a `print_r` on my array, I get the following output;

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 178
            [name] => Briar Price
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 90
            [name] => Bradley Kramer
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 508
            [name] => Calvin Yang
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [id] => 457
            [name] => Charles Valenzuela
        )

    ... and so on
```

How can I modify the array to look like this;

```
Array
(
    [178] => Briar Price
    [90] => Bradley Kramer
    [508] => Calvin Yang
    [457] => Charles Valenzuela
    ... and so on
)
```

I just want to make the ID the key for the value name. I always have issues when it comes to arrays reordering.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [foreach()](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) -

```
$newArr = array();
foreach ($your_array as $key => $val) {
  $newArr[$val['id']] = $val['name'];
}

print_r($newArr) // desired output
```

Comment: Although all answers are good, I'm going to accept this one as the correct answer. I had a foreach in mind but how to implement it confuses me always. I'll learn from this one (but from all other's as well. Everybody, have my upvote).

Answer (score 5):

Pass third parameter to [**`array_column`**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) to make its key as

```
$array = array_column($users, 'name', 'id');

print_r($array);
```

Comment: Sam answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/37919187/3933332 a few days ago.

Comment: For some reason I get an error when trying to do it this way; `Attempted to call function "array_column" from namespace my\namespace`

Comment: @Mentos93 try adding a slash in front: `\array_column(...)`

Comment: @Saty I won't link to the exact same answer from 4 days ago: http://stackoverflow.com/a/38264062 because that doesn't yield the exact output from OP's question there.

Comment: Adding a slash give the same error but from the global namespace. But it's ok, I understand what's going on here.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it using [array_column](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) and [array_combine](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php) **PHP** function without applying custom logic.

Here is how you do it,

```
<?php
    $keys=array_column($mainarray,'id');
    $values=array_column($mainarray,'name');

    $finalarray=array_combine($keys,$values);
```

`$finalarray` will be your desired result.

> **array_combine** creates an array by using one array for keys and another for its values.
>
> **array_column** returns the values from a single column in the input array.

Comment: array_column() expects parameter 1 to be array, string given

Comment: My bad! Corrected it, Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

I'd use `array_combine` which attaches new keys to values

```
$results = [
    ['id'=>1,'name'=>'John'],['id'=>2,'name'=>'Jane'],
];

$results = array_combine(
    array_column($results,'id'), //use 'id' column as keys
    array_column($results,'name') //use 'name' column as values
);
//now $results is [1=>'John', 2=>'Jane']
```

Comment: Little lengthy but correct!!

Comment: Why lengthy? It's one line of code, formatted and commented to be easy to read. It's just not as elegant as your solution

Comment: lengthy in the sense of using to many array function!!